# External table in Hive from two parquet files

Tags: hive, parquet, external-tables

**Question in short,**
Is it possible to mount an external hive table on top of multiple files with differing schema, where the table is all or a subset of the total of all columns in those files specified?

I know, the question is bit complex, see the scenario in detail
   below.

I do have two parquet files, with differing schema in two different locations, partitioned by `yyyymmdd` format

```
/app/data/source/file-1/20170501/file-1.pqt
/app/data/source/file-2/20170501/file-2.pqt
```

Let's assume file one is like this; and for the time being, the files are in Parquet format.

```
File-1
ID|Name
1|My Zone

File-2
APP ID, APP Name, APP owner
1,My App, Manager-1
```

I want it to be mounted on top an external Hive table.
Where, when some body issues a command select * from table, he gets the result.

```
ID, Name, App Name, App Owner
1, My Zone, NULL, NULL
1, NULL, My APP, Manager-1
```

If not possible what is the best recommended method?
btw, please note that both the files are entirely different source files, not an evolved schema.